# GroupBy within bucket and get max count within that interval

Tags: kibana, elk, timelion

I have an index that outputs objects and status of that object every 30 seconds. Number of objects remain constant each 30 seconds, but their state can change. I'm trying to generate a graph using timelion of the count of objects in a specific state.

This works fine when my interval is less than 30 seconds, but once they start getting bucketed together, I get double (or more) counts of the items. So I'm trying to get a max count of items in a given state within each interval. I'm not sure if this is possible in timelion.

t = 0: object1 = A, object2 = A, object3 = B, object4=A  (so objects in state A would be 3) 
t = 30: object1 = A, object2 = B, object3 = B, object4=A (objects in A would be 2) 
t = 60: object1 = A, object2 = B, object3 = B, object4=A (objects in A would be 2) 
t = 90: object1 = B, object2 = B, object3 = B, object4=A (objects in A would be 1)

With the above set, I would get a count of 3 the first publish, then 2, then 2 and then 1. If I chart a count of this with a 1m interval, it would count 5 (3 + 2) and then 3 (2 + 1), but I want the max of any publish within that hour, so I would want 3 and then 2.

Is there any way I can do this in timelion?